# border collapse with rollover on list with border

Tags: html, css

I am trying to give my `li` a 1px border. There are is no margin and no padding between the `li`.

`border-collapse:collapse;` does not work in this case. So The only thing I came across being able to do is to give them `border-bottom` and `border-right`.

This works well. But the issue is if I want the border to change color on hover. then only the bottom and right border change color.

Is there any other way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try something like following. The padding below may be omitted.

CSS

```
ul{
    border: 0 solid #ddd;
    border-width: 0 0 1px 1px;
    margin:0px; padding:0px;
}

li{
    border: 0 solid #ddd;
    border-width: 1px 1px 0 0;
    padding:.5em;
}

li:hover{
    border: 1px solid #ff0000;    
}
```

Or

```
li {
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
}

li:not(:first-child) {
    border-top: 0;
}

li:hover{
    border-top: 1px;
    border: 1px solid #ff0000;    
}
```

HTML

```
<ul>
    <li>first bullet</li>
    <li>second bullet</li>
    <li>third bullet</li>
</ul>
```

[First jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/g2k0u1hg/2/) | [Second jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3h8bm/26/)

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
li {
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 1px;
}
```

[JS Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/g2k0u1hg/1/)

Comment: The border between first and second are doubled arent they? Same for between 2nd and 3rd.

Comment: Yes, they are.  I am not sure if you can do anything about that if you want zero padding.  Another option would be to eliminate border-top and border-bottom for middle <li> elements but that would bring back your other problem.